# How can the ipmiutil to check the power status?

Tags: ipmi, ipmiutil

How can the ipmiutil to check the power status?

we know we can use the bellow methods to power on/off the server:

```
power down：ipmiutil power -d -N fsp_ip_address -P ipmi_password
power on：  ipmiutil power -u -N fsp_ip_address -P ipmi_password
```

but how can we to check the power status?

Answer (score 0):

Power status can be read via `health` command. It shows a lot of information including `chassis_power = on`

```
$ ipmiutil health -N 10.0.0.1 -P user -U password
ipmiutil ver 2.85
ihealth ver 2.85
Opening lan connection to node 10.0.0.1 ...
Connecting to node 10.0.0.1
BMC version       = a.00, IPMI v2.0
BMC manufacturer  = 000af2 ( ), product = 0037
IPMI driver type  = 6        (lan)
Power State       = 00       (S0: working)
Selftest status   = 0055     (OK)
Chassis Status    = 41 10 40 00 (on, see below)
         chassis_power       = on
         pwr_restore_policy  = turn_on
         last_power_event    = IPMI
         chassis_intrusion   = inactive
         front_panel_lockout = inactive
         drive_fault         = false
         cooling_fan_fault   = false
Power On Hours    = 7280 hours (303 days)
BMC LAN Channels  = 1 8
Chan 1 AuthTypes  = MD5
ipmiutil health, completed successfully
```